# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (however they are str)

Tags: python

Please help me, I don't understand this error.

I made str but they don't work and I have an error - can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

```
import re 
text = 'a3b4c2e13b1'

numbs = re.findall(r'\d\d|\d',text)
letters = re.findall(r'\D',text)

numbs_str = ','.join(numbs)
letters_str = ','.join(letters)

for i in range(len(letters_str)):
    result = letters_str[i] * numbs_str[i]
```

I need from the numbers make the number of letters like this: 
a3b4c2e13b1
aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeeeeb

Comment: Hi! What are you trying to achieve in that loop? I see that you are multiplicating letters? That's why the error - when you're multiplying you need at least one of the variables to be an int.

Comment: Yes, they are both strings, and multiplying two strings makes no sense, and as the error message suggest, you can only multiply a string by an int.

Comment: You took a wrong turn when you `join`ed the regex results into strings. Iterating over `"a,b,c,e,b"` is not the same as iterating over `["a", "b", "c", "e", "b"]`, and `"3,4,2,13,1"[1]` is `","`, not `"4"` or `4`.

Comment: Thank you all! Your comments helped me to understand and to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `zip` and `str.join`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
text = 'a3b4c2e13b1'

numbs = re.findall(r'(\d+)',text)
letters = re.findall(r'(\D)',text)

print("".join(k*int(v) for k, v in zip(letters, numbs)))
```

**Output:**

```
aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeeeeb
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of multiply str into str. 
you need to multiple str into int.

So ,You can update the code like this

```
import re 
text = 'a3b4c2e13b1'

numbs = re.findall(r'\d\d|\d',text)
letters = re.findall(r'\D',text)

numbs_str = map(int, numbs)

result = ""
for le, num in zip(letters, numbs_str):
    result += le * num
print(result)
```

**output**

```
 aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeeeeb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove"," while joining the number and alphabet list. Also typecast the numbers to int.

```
import re 
text = 'a3b4c2e13b1'

numbs = re.findall(r'\d\d|\d',text)
letters = re.findall(r'\D',text)

numbs_str = ''.join(numbs)
letters_str = ''.join(letters)

result=""
for i in range(len(letters_str)):
    result = result+letters_str[i] * int(numbs_str[i])

print(result)
```

the result is "aaabbbbccebbb"

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer with solution, but let's think a bit what you are trying to get.
Lets say regexes... are "ok", and in your solution you create lists with results (numbs_str and letters_str).

inside your for loop, when you iterate your strings with range(len()) in results, your are trying also duplicate ',' because they are also a part of your string.
It will not work for sure. Anyway, if you want to duplicate the word, multiply it by integer, not a string.

Some very simple solution, without maps and zips. As you can see, I convert str to integer, when I hit a number. Work on lists, not strings.

```
import re
text = 'a3b4c2e13b1'

numbs = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
letters = re.findall(r'\D', text)

numbs_str = ','.join(numbs)
letters_str = ','.join(letters)

# for i in range(len(letters_str)):
#     result = letters_str[i] * numbs_str[i]
#     print(result)

print(numbs)
print(letters)
print(numbs_str)
print(letters_str)

contents = []
for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
    contents.append(letter * int(numbs[index]))

print("".join(contents))
```

Result:

```
['3', '4', '2', '13', '1']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'b']
3,4,2,13,1
a,b,c,e,b
aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeeeeb
```